# C# WPF XAML Minimap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How I can build a minimap like in Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio, Sublime Text?

[Minimap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i26b5.png)

I have 2 horizontal StackPanels.

Top: StackPanel with content

Bottom: Minimap StackPanel with Height 100 just shows the content from the top StackPanel in miniature without adding the same content from the top StackPanel.

```
<Grid>

    <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="scrollViewer"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <WrapPanel
            x:Name="wrapPanel"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="0,0,0,100" />
    </ScrollViewer>

    <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="scrollViewerMiniMap"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Height="100">
        <WrapPanel
            x:Name="wrapPanelMiniMap"
            Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Fill a Rectangle with a VisualBrush.

Comment: Just create a `VisualBrush` from the content e.g. using the root container of the content. Override the default style for the `ScrollViewer` to paint the background of the track with the VisualBrush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `VisualBrush` from the content e.g. using the root container of the content. Override the default style for the `ScrollViewer` to paint the background of the track with the `VisualBrush`.

To create a simple dynamic preview just use a `Rectangle` and set `Fill` to the `VisualBrush`. If you want to allow resizing host the `Rectangle` inside a `ViewBox`.

To get an initial width with the correct aspect ratio just bind the `Rectangle` to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of the container element that serves as the `Visual` for the `VisualBrush`:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="VisualBrush" 
                 Visual="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel}"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" 
              Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="ComboBox1 Label" />
      <ComboBox />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="ComboBox2 Label" />
      <ComboBox />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>

  <Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
    <Rectangle Width="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel, Path=ActualWidth}"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel, Path=ActualHeight}"
               Fill="{StaticResource VisualBrush}" />
  </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```